# How to efficiently multiply a list of NumPy views with corresponding weights?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization, memory-management

I am facing a memory and speed problem using NumPy but my issue is quite simple.

- `A` is a large NumPy array of `H * W` integers.
- `V` is a list containing `N` views of the large array `A`, each view as the same `(Hv, Wv)` shape.
- `K` is another list containing `N` float weights corresponding to the views.

`Hv` are `Wv` are almost equal to `H` and `W` but smaller. As [NumPy views](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) are not copies, this is nice for memory management, even if `N` is big.

Now, I want to compute a new array using broadcasting for speed: **B = V<sub>1</sub>*K<sub>1</sub> + ... + V<sub>N</sub>*K<sub>N</sub>**

This will result in a new `Hv * Wv` weighted array.

The issue is that I do not know how to perform such operation without creating intermediate arrays in memory (which is what happens when a view is multiplied with the corresponding weight) and while benefiting from broadcast operations.

```
import numpy as np

H = W = 1000
Hv = Wv = 900
N = 100

A = np.arange(H * W).reshape(H, W)

V = [A[i:Hv + i, i:Wv + i] for i in range(N)]

K = np.random.rand(N)

# It neither uses speed broadcast nor low memory!
B = sum(v*k for v, k in zip(V, K))
```

Could someone help me to make a smart use of NumPy, please?

Comment: It seems `A` holds the weights? So, would be more reasonable to use a sample with random numbers in it rather than just `ones`, right?

Comment: Haven't you over-simplified with : `V = [A[:Hv, :Wv] for _ in range(N)]` as V[0], V[1], etc would be the same?

Comment: @Divakar I thought this was enough to understand the problem, but this is true it does not look at all like real data. I updated my question with an array of sliding diagonal views, I hope it is better (but it works because `N = H - Hv` and would raise an error otherwise).

Comment: Isn't there a fixed way that you might be using to create `V`? So, I guess we can just say that `V` would be given and we don't need to worry about optimizing creating `V`?

Comment: @Divakar Exactly! I have plenty of time to create `A`, `V` and `K`, but I will often need to compute `B` with some values of `A` updated (which is also why I use views). I only concerned about speed and memory managment while creating `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming `V` is given as a list and we have don't have access to optimize creating it or just don't need to. So, `A` is out of the equation and we are left with `V` and `K` to get to final output `B` and thus, left with optimizing the last step.

To solve it, we can just use [`np.tensordot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) to replace the last step of sum-reduction as that's basically sum-reduction of a matrix-multiplication. In our case, we are reducing the first axis from `K` and along the length of input list `V`. Internally, NumPy would convert the list to a NumPy tensor array and that length would become the first axis of its array version. Thus, we would be reducing the first axis from both these inputs and therefore the implementation would be -

```
B = np.tensordot(K,V,axes=[0,0]) # `axes` indicates the axes to be sum-reduced
```

Please note that the internal conversion of list to NumPy array might not be inexpensive and as such it would make more sense to create `V` using initialization as a NumPy array, rather than in a loop comprehension that would result in a list.

Comment: Oh, this looks complicated, I could never have figure this out, thank you. I am sorry but as I edited my question to simplify it, the variable `coords` no longer makes sense.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your time, the solution and explanations are much appreciated! However, I am still confused about memory usage of NumPy. While the solution using `np.tensordot` seems faster and [lighter](http://pastebin.com/raw/a1emehwQ) (not as much as I thought it will, so my assumption that multiplying a view with a float produced huge memory usage was maybe wrong), initializing `V` as a NumPy array leads to [an unexpected increment of the memory usage](http://pastebin.com/raw/ct0kSTG2). Am I doing something wrong with the profiling, or is there something I should know?

Comment: @Delgan Ah not like that, that would create a list and then convert to array! I meant like V = np.zeros((N,Hv,Wv)) and use a proper loop instead of loop comprehension to store at each iteration into V[0] = .., V[1] = ... and so on. If using a proper loop isn't possible for some reason, stick to what you had before as a list.

Comment: This produces [weird and even worse results](http://pastebin.com/raw/emrm9yGb) but I think this is because my views objects are converted and their values are copied into `K`. I guess this is also what happened when casting my list to a `np.array`. I think I should stay with the list solution, even if the internal conversion is expensive, because I need the views, I want to compute a new `B` array after some changes made on `A`, right?

Comment: So, if you keep on the creation `V` with loop comprehension and use `np.tensordot` to get `B`, how would that compare against the original solution in terms of memory and performance?

Comment: It is better, [from what I tested and shared in a previous comment](http://pastebin.com/raw/a1emehwQ), for both speed and memory usage. So it somehow solves my issue which actually was not a real issue, as the original solution appears to not be far behind yours (which is in the end the best, thank you!).

Comment: @Delgan Hmm I see. I think performance wise the improvement would be noticeable. Glad to see some improvement on the memory side nevertheless!

Comment: I did not notice that at first because I made some tests on different data (the one of my real problem), but your solution appears to be [almost twice as fast](http://pastebin.com/raw/qZK8Jgww) with the example of my question, so `np.tensordot` is a real improvement!